# animation package saveHTML() issue

Tags: r, animation

I am testing the basic `saveHTML()` functionality in the `animation` package. I encounter a bug which I am not able to resolve.

Reproducible example:

```
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)
saveHTML({for (i in 1:10) plot(runif(10))},htmlfile = "test1.html")
saveHTML({for (i in 1:5) qplot(runif(10))},htmlfile = "test2.html")
```

The first command will create 10 frames, but the second command overwrites only the first 5 frames and continues to use the last 5 frames of the first command.

Even when I give different html file names, the problem persists.

Comment: If you remove generated plots in `images` folder between `saveHTML` calls, it works.

Comment: Thanks! that did work.